# How to set OpenVPN client to force traffic through VPN Server?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

The OpenVPN client and server are setup and run very well. However, the network traffic goes from client to VPN Server only for internal traffic (e.g. *.mydomain.com)

I have heard some setting on the server site that enable/disable all traffic or just internal traffic (otherwise the common network e.g. google.com will go through its existing network as of no VPN connection)

Is there any setting I can change on the client side to accomplish that as well?

Comment: #push "redirect-gateway def1"
#push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

Answer (score 1):

Note entirely sure that this is what you are looking for, but you can force all client traffic through the VPN by setting the `redirect-gateway def1`-parameter.

> Pushing the redirect-gateway option to clients will cause all IP network traffic originating on client machines to pass through the OpenVPN server.

More information in the official how to: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect

Comment: Hi this is the thing I am trying to accomplish, but it is server setting. Could I get the client setting to accomplish that without server changing?

Comment: Sure! You can simply add that parameter to your .openvpn-config file on the client side - without having to change the server config.